# Helm not merging array of secrets

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to do merge of multiple values files which has array of secrets.But the merging is not working instead the last values file overrides.
This is my secret template

```
---
{{- range  .Values.secrets }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
   name: {{ required "a valid name is required" .name }}
   namespace: ""
type: Opaque
data:
   {{- range $key, $val := .data }}
     # fix printing the key name in the required string
     {{ $key }}: {{ required "a valid key is required" $val }}
   {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

value1.yaml:

```
secrets:
- name: "sample"
 data:
   test: "YXBpa2V5MQo="
```

value2.yaml:

```
- name: "sample2"
 data:
   test: "YXBpa2V5MQo="

helm template secrets-template -f value1.yaml -f value2.yaml
```

The output is

```
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
   name: sample2
   namespace: ""
type: Opaque
data:
     # fix printing the key name in the required string
     test: YXBpa2V5MQo=
```

But the expected output is

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
   name: sample
   namespace: ""
type: Opaque
data:
     # fix printing the key name in the required string
     test: YXBpa2V5MQo=
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
   name: sample2
   namespace: ""
type: Opaque
data:
     # fix printing the key name in the required string
     test: YXBpa2V5MQo=
```

Any help on this ?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, helm always overwrites arrays. A work around, is to use dictionaries. For example, use the name of the secret as the key.

template:

```
---
{{- range  $secretName, $secretValue := .Values.secrets }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
   name: {{ required "a valid name is required" $secretName }}
   namespace: ""
type: Opaque
data:
   {{- range $key, $val := $secretValue }}
     # fix printing the key name in the required string
     {{ $key }}: {{ required "a valid key is required" $val }}
   {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

value1.yaml

```
secrets:
 sample: 
   test: "YXBpa2V5MQo="
```

value2.yaml

```
secrets:
 sample2: 
   test: "YXBpa2V5MQo="
```

Comment: Thankyou..it works..I did a small modification.{{- range $secretName,$secretValue := .Values.secrets }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: {{ required "a valid name is required" $secretName }}
type: {{  $secretValue.type | default "Opaque" }}
data:
    {{- range $key, $val := $secretValue.data }}
      # fix printing the key name in the required string
      {{ $key }}: {{ required "a valid key is required" $val }}
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}coalesce.go:160: warning: skipped value for secrets: Not a table.